# FabricJS deserialize in bigger canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to deserialize a serialized canvas to another canvas which is bigger, how do I manage to move all the elements from the serialized JSON so I can fix the position on the new canvas?

Comment: The position won't change if you deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended using this, passing the json objects that FabricJs generate

> fabric.util.enlivenObjects()

then i fixed the positon of the elements and added to the new canvas

```
   var iOCanvasJSON = JSON.stringify(baseCanvas);
   var jsonO = JSON.parse(iOCanvasJSON);       

   fabric.util.enlivenObjects(jsonO.objects, function (enlivenedObjects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < enlivenedObjects.length; i++) {
            var oldTop = enlivenedObjects[i].top ;
            enlivenedObjects[i].top = oldTop + 100;
            canvasO.add(enlivenedObjects[i]);
        }
        canvasO.renderAll();
    });
```

Comment: this is more or less the way to do it, there is a simpler one if you want.

Comment: How would it be the simpler one?

Comment: if you need to adapt the new objects to a bigger canvas, you can just calculate how much you should zoom the old canvas to fit the new size, and then apply the zoom. No modification is required to object positions since everything scales. Also you can choose between a fit or cover approach

Comment: It is not working in new version of 'fabric' `4.2.0`. I got the error `Expected 3-4 arguments, but got 2.`. They added a third argument named 'namespace'. But i don't know what it is.